# Correct usage of date format in a sentence

Tags: dates

I have an example here.

> Payment of $45 from 20 Aug 16 to 20 Sep 16 has been made successfully.

Is is right to frame a date this way for the user to read it easily or is there any other way to format a date in sentences like above?

Comment: The sentence you give makes perfect sense and would be clearly understood by all.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I’d have to disagree with that. The date format is fine, but I don’t see how a payment itself can be _from_ some date _to_ another. A payment is a payment: it takes place once, at a particular time; not over the course of a month. I suspect what is really meant is something like, “Payment of $45 for/covering the period of 20 Aug 2016 – 20 Sep 2016 has been successfully made”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree with you there, I had only looked at the date format, I should have looked at the wider sentence

Comment: This is exactly not the case. I just had given an example. The actual word there is - Past Due @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: The preferred date format varies by country and culture.  "Aug 20, 2016 to Sept 16, 2016" would generally be preferred in the US.

Comment: Hemalatha, did you notice the phrase "past due" crops up first in your later Comment of Aug 26 '16 at 5:00, not in the original Question, nor Comments between? Where would you insert "past due" into the OQ?

Answer (score -2):

"The date is 20 Aug 16…" should show that in the example the date format is fine; the rest of the phrase merely confusing.

Comment: The use of two-digit years is highly suspect.

Comment: Before both false and real millenniums, two-digit years terrified the ignorant; nothing more. In the context, US date formats are clearly wrong to use months then days then years. “Time” is a human construct, but it passes as days then months then years. While it’s true that “ ’16” with an apostrophe is more “correct” than “16” alone, that’s a different question than whether either is “suspect”. Those who see the millennium bug as a dead duck tend to find “2016” or “ ’16” or “16” roughly equally acceptable, perhaps depending on circumstances.